# Setting value of dropdown programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive which I want to change the value of on a click event. This is the controller that the click event is being triggered (I have removed all irrelevant code) :

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    //getting the existing module
    angular.module("app")
        .controller("teamsController", teamsController);

    //inject http service
    function teamsController($scope, $http, divisionService, $rootScope) {

        $scope.divisions = divisionService.all();

        var vm = this;

        vm.teams = [];

        vm.newTeam = {};

        vm.editTeam = function (team) {

            $rootScope.$broadcast('someEvent', [team.division]);
}
```

And here is where the event is being captured :

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    //getting the existing module
    angular.module("app")
        .controller("divisionsController", divisionsController)
        .directive("divisionDropdown", divisionDropdown);

    //inject http service
    function divisionsController($http, $scope, divisionService, $rootScope) {

        $scope.divisions = divisionService.all();

        $rootScope.$on('someEvent', function (event, selectedDiv) {
            alert(selectedDiv);
            $rootScope.selectedDivision = selectedDiv;
        });
    };

    function divisionDropdown() {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: false,
            controller: "divisionsController",
            template: "<select class='form-control' ng-model='selectedDivision' ng-options='division.divisionName for division in divisions' required>\
                                <option style='display:none' value=''>{{'Select'}}</option>\
                            </select>"
        };
    }
})();
```

And this is the divisionService, which I am using to populate the dropdown intially :

```
app.factory("divisionService", function ($http) {

        var divisions = [];

        var errorMessage = "";
        var isBusy = true;

        //matched to verb, returns promise
        $http.get('http://localhost:33201/api/Divisions')
            .then(function (response) {
                //first parameter is on success
                //copy response.data to vm.divisions (could alternatively use a foreach)
                angular.copy(response.data, divisions);
            }, function (error) {
                //second parameter is on failure
                errorMessage = "Failed to load data: " + error;
            })
            .finally(function () {
                isBusy = false;
            });

        return {
            all: function () {
                return divisions;
            },
            first: function () {
                return divisions[0];
            }
        };
    });
```

But I am not able to get the selectedDivision in the dropdown to change on the click event.  Can anybody tell me how do I refer to it and reset it? I am not that familiar with scoping in Angular so my usage of $scope and $rootScope is possibly where the issue lies.

Comment: You need to have your directive in the html template of the controller (teamscontroller) where you want to access it. Then, you can use a shared scope of the directive to access the value of the directive or pass a reference as an argument to the directive (you have ``scope: false``, so it is actually the exact same scope as in the outer context. Just use ``$scope.selectedDivision`` in the controller which contains this directive.

Comment: I need to access the directive in both the teamsController and the divisionsController, would I have to put it in both controllers?

Comment: A controller contains the logic of a HTML website (mostly one page). A directive is a HTML snippet with its own controller which acts as a module inside another controller. You can add a directive by adding the HTML-tag of the directive (``<divisionDropdown />``) to any page. If you add such a tag to your parent HTML struture, it is converted to the the template you specified in the directive. Whenever you need such a dropdown, you need to add the directive HTML tag to the template. By doing that (and using ``scope: false``) you can directly access the scope variables from the outer context.

Comment: So, if you need to have the directive in teamsController and divisionsController, you need to add the HTML tag of the directive in both HTML templates. You can then access the property ``$scope.selectedDivision`` directly in the parent scope. This is however not a nice solution. It is better to have an own scope for every directive. Then, you can specify which arguments are accessible in the directive and also the outer controller. You can do that by writing ``scope: { selectedDivision: '=' }`` and adding it with ``<divisionDropdown selectedDivision="selectedDivision">``).

Comment: The variable selectedDivision (what is inside the two ``" "``) is then manipulateable in both: the directive and the outer controller. Everything else is kept in its own garden :)

Comment: And  I would access this through $scope.selectedDivision?

Comment: With ``scope:false`` you can access it in both controllers with ``$scope.selectedDivision``. With ``scope: { selectedDivision: '=' }`` you can access it in the directive with ``$scope.selectedDivision`` and in the outer controller, you can pass any reference: ``<divisionDropdown selectedDivision="some.name">``. You can then access it in the outer controller with ``$scope.some.name``. Of course, it would make sense to use the same name as suggested above. Both variables should always have the same value (the ``'='`` makes sure that it is that way)